Discord Bot allows reaction B if reaction A been added first
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if client.user == user:
        return
    if user != reaction.message.author and reaction.emoji not in ('', ''):
        await reaction.remove(user)

Right now Im allowing members to use only 2 reactions total.
What I want is to make them react with first one ('') so they can react with another one ('') otherwise bot will remove it.
Can someone help me with that? Sounds fairly easy but Im already worn out.
No buttons please.
I have tried asyncio for user in users but that didnt work.
I'm not quite sure how to call a regular reacting user in the code and don't really know how to do it at all :(
@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
    if client.user == user:
        return
    print("1")
    if user and (reaction.emoji) in ("", ""):
        channel = client.get_channel(1245472750164906084)
        print("2")
        await channel.send(f"{user.display_name} removed reaction {reaction.emoji}")
        print("3")

This doesn't work - not even getting into print 1

Why are you using the on_reaction_remove event? The logic of your problem only requires your bot to check if the user has already reacted with  when a  reaction is added.
import discord


@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction: discord.Reaction, user: discord.User):
    if client.user == user:
        return
    elif user != reaction.message.author and reaction.emoji not in ('', ''):
        await reaction.remove(user)
    elif reaction.emoji == '':
        leg_reaction = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.reactions, emoji='')
        is_leg_user = False
        async for leg_user in leg_reaction.users():
            if leg_user == user:
                is_leg_user = True
                break
        if not is_leg_user:
            await reaction.remove(user)


Documentation for Reaction.users().


This is exactly what I've been looking for. This is a bit harder than the rest of the things I've been doing so far, really happy you helped me with this. Thank you so much.

One more thing. When I react with leg then with thumb and remove leg, the thumbs up stays. Is there any way that bot can remove it if same person remove leg reaction?

You'll do something similar to the one shown above, but using the on_reaction_remove event. When the user removes the reaction, you'll check if they've also reacted with and if so, remove the user's `` reaction.
